# yet another elusive non exhaustive match

Tags: scala, scalac

I get the following match warning.

"*match may not be exhaustive. It would fail on the following input: Some((x: Abstract forSome x not in (A, B, C)))*"

code:

```
abstract class Abstract
case class A() extends Abstract
case class B() extends Abstract
case class C() extends Abstract

class matcher {
  def matcher(a: Option[Abstract]) = a match {
    case None      => true  
    case Some(A()) => false 
    case Some(B()) => false 
    case Some(C()) => false 
  }
}
```

In case you wonder, the case classes here have no arguments but in my real code they do. I hope the answer is not "the compiler can't know whether or not there are additional subclassess of `Abstract` somewhere in the program...

Is making the abstract class sealed the only solution? scala is not a very dynamic language, so how come the compiler doesn't know that the group mentioned in the compilation warning is an empty group?

Comment: Yes, making `Abstract` `sealed` is the only solution, other than matching `_`. Given the question, why would you not want to make it `sealed`? Of course implementations can be added at run time - just add a library with some more `Abstract` implementations. The compiler can only know the _compiletime_ classpath and never the _runtime_  classpath.

Comment: @BoristheSpider I reworded a little to focus the question on the latter aspect. Not sure how adding a library at runtime is possible, in swaying the compiler off its feat knowing its types. Care to try an answer?

Comment: What? One major selling point of the JVM is that you create an trait/interface and compile against it; only supplying the implementation at run time. Of course the compiler doesn't know all possible types that can be. There is nothing to stop you including a `case class Z() extends Abstract` is another compilation unit.

Comment: Would a case in point be that my code were to be a library, and it will have been used by a user project, that extended my unsealed abstract type?

Comment: Most definitely a very good example, yes.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably not ideal but it'll work if you don't want to seal Abstract.

```
abstract class Abstract
sealed abstract class SealedAbstract
case class A() extends SealedAbstract
case class B() extends SealedAbstract
case class C() extends SealedAbstract

class matcher {
    def matcher(a: Option[Abstract]) = a match {
        case None => true  
        case Some(thing) => matcher(thing)
    }
    def matcher(a: Abstract) = a match{
        case seal: SealedAbstract => matcher(seal)
        case _ => false
    }
    //this will be exhaustive
    def matcher(a: SealedAbstract) a match{
        case A() => false
        case B() => false
        case C() => false
    }
}
```

A better (and more maintainable/extensible) way to perform logic against the Abstract objects is using type classes.

```
abstract class Abstract
sealed abstract class SealedAbstract
case class A() extends SealedAbstract
case class B() extends SealedAbstract
case class C() extends SealedAbstract

trait PerformAction[Type <: Abstract]{def doSomething(in: Type): String}
implicit object SealedPerformAction extends PerformAction[SealedAbstract]{
    override def doSomething(sa: SealedAbstract): String = "It does."
}

class matcher {
    def doIfExists[Type <: Abstract](a: Option[Type])(implicit ev: PerformAction[Type]): String = a match{
        case None => ""
        case Some(thing) => ev.doSomething(thing)
    }
}
```

With a type class you get the exhaustive pattern matching and you get type safety outside of your library as any user of your library must implement a PerformAction if she implements her own Abstract.